# Dune behaviour regarding .cma files

Tags: ocaml, utop, ocaml-dune

I am experiencing some issues when trying to create a `.cma` file (library) with the `dune` utility. I have the following project tree:

```
.
├── _build
│   ├── default
│   │   ├── dune
│   │   └── lib
│   │       ├── a.a
│   │       ├── a.cma
│   │       ├── a.cmxa
│   │       ├── a.cmxs
│   │       ├── a.ml
│   │       └── dune
│   └── log
├── dune
├── dune-project
└── lib
    ├── a.ml
    └── dune
```

Where `a.ml` declares a very simple function `f`, as an example. When I run directly `ocamlc -o a.cma -a a.ml`, and then fire up `utop a.cma`, I am able to perform, as desired, the following command:

```
utop # A.f;;
- : int -> int = <fun>
```

On the other hand, after one use of `dune build` (which generates the `_build` directory and its sub-directories), the `_build/default/lib/a.cma` file that I get takes ten times as much space as the manually-generated one, and more importantly, does not work. Both commands `utop _build/default/lib/a.cma` and `cd _build/default/lib; utop a.cma` are unsuccesful and I am unable to use the module `A`:

```
utop # A.f;;
Line 1, characters 0-3:
Error: Unbound module A
```

I know about the `dune utop` command, but what if I want to export/share my library elsewhere, where `dune` is not installed? What am I supposed to do? Am I using `dune` the wrong way? Thank you in advance

---

PS: File content:

**lib/dune**

```
(library
 (name a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make visible the bytecode object files in `.a.objs/byte`. For instance with:

```ml
#directory ".a.objs/byte"
```

(Those files are installed as usual for library users)

Also note that dune is by default in wrapped mode: the module `M` from library `Lib` is accessible as `Lib.M`, except if the user defines an entry point module with the the same name `Lib` as the whole library.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any explanation as to why it is like this (i.e. `.cmi` file inside this hidden folder and... 'useless' `.cmi` file next to the `.cma` file)? standard libraries don't have such folders in my installation.

Comment: The compilation artifacts in build are not really intended to be directly used (without an installation step). Those issues are not present once the library installed.